# Prevent users to connect to a PostgreSQL database while using it in Python3?

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x

I have made a program in Python3 which works with some PostgreSQL databases in very different ways (dumping, dropping, replicating them, etc...). The fact is that when for example, I want to dump a database, the program does it and before this it terminates automatically every connection to the mentioned database (except for mine).

What I need to do now is to be sure nobody is going to connect to the database during the dumping process. I was thinking about changing the property "datallowconn" of the target database to 0, and after the dumping process, set it again to 1. But I do not know whether this is the best way or not.

Anyone can help me with this, is there a better way to manage this?

Comment: Just REVOKE CONNECT for this database and these users, drop all current connections and do your stuff.

Comment: So for example:
REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE database_name FROM { role_name | PUBLIC } [ CASCADE | RESTRICT ]
What should I choose after FROM? And if I run this query, it will be temporarily or permanent?

Comment: You do realize that in Postgres you can work on a database and execute a consistent dump at the same time? There's no need to prevent concurrent connections while using `pg_dump`.

Comment: I did not know that, thank you. But, suppossing the program is going to do an action over the database which needs the fact of nobody being connected. The query will be REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE my_database FROM PUBLIC; and once the action finishes, GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE my_database TO PUBLIC;? I was trying to do this but I am still being able to connect to my_database from pgAdmin III just after the first query and before the second one.